# JQL ORDER BY clause and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, jql

Let's say I have an entity class `A`, two entity classes `B` and `C` which inherits from `A`, and entity class `D` which inherits from `C`. `A` and `C` are abstract entities. Entity `A` has a field `name`. How one could construct a JQL-query which orders entities by name **within** each entity class. Entities of class `B` sorted by `name` should go first, then should go entities of class `B` (also sorted by name), and then of class `D`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select a from A a order by Type(a), a.name
```

The Type() function was added in JPA 2.0.  Previously you would need to map the type field to be able to query on it.